# Is there a support for regular expression in Idris?

Tags: regex, idris

I don't see regular expression in Idris documentation, is it supported in any (preferrably portable) way? Or is it planned?

Comment: Just putting it here: https://github.com/idris-hackers/IdrisScript/blob/master/IdrisScript/RegExps.idr

Comment: I would have to precise regex w/o JS

Comment: As soon as you write one, there will be one! I suggest you look at the Haskell package `regex-applicative` for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Idris documentation has no mentioning of a built-in regex engine. (Interestingly, [Haskell has a regex module](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=regex).) [Idris Man page](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/man/idris.1) states that it might lack a lot of things:

> It is important to note that Idris is first and foremost a research
>   tool and project. Thus the tooling provided and resulting programs
>   created should not necessarily be seen as production ready nor for
>   industrial use.

So, using [IdrisScript](https://github.com/idris-hackers/IdrisScript/blob/master/IdrisScript/RegExps.idr) seems to be a pertinent workaround.

Comment: Note that Haskell has many regex libraries, but no regex support by default.(i.e. no regex in `base` and no special syntax)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/rodrigogribeiro/idrisregexp) is my regex matching tool in Idris.

The matching algorithm is proven correct using the notion of derivatives. Hope that it could help.

Comment: Can it be used from inside Idris to check if a string starts with some regexp and if so, extract the matching string and the remainder, e.g., with regexp groups?

Comment: Hi! I've implemented a decision procedure for matching prefixes and substrings of a regex. So, you can extract both if you want to.